# Best practices for creating various language-packs on a site? PHP

Tags: php, language-agnostic, language-packs

I've created a language pack for a site before, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the best method.

Basically, all I have is a file with variables defining string constants.  Usually a set of arrays where an array usually refers to a particular elements of the site.

Then the site code just includes the appropriate file based on a flag and then echo's out the appropriate array element.

What are some ways of doing this to reduce maintenance headaches and performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html). It is somewhat a combination of the other suggestions people left here, only more maintainable and better designed.

You can switch adapters depending on your preference (supports gettext, csv and a multitude of others), you don't need defines or globals polluting your global scope and it is well documented.

Comment: I'll second this as in some cases Gettext is not thread safe so on some setups Gettext will be a thorn in your side, plus it depends on that extension being installed. Zend_Translate implements multiple common methods from Gettext to XML based translations and is integrated in other components

Answer (score 1):

The best option you could have, with PHP, is [GetText](http://be.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), but not all the server have it built-in, so it may be a show stopper if you're managing your server.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of the most common ways to do this are:

1) Use `define('SOME_STRING', 'Some string');` - simply have a different file stuffed with these defines for each language.  This is very easy, and you don't have to use "global" all over the place.

2) Wrap strings in a function: `translate('My String')` - this is more flexible as you can parse your code to create lists of strings to translate, and add in features like variables, e.g. `translate('I can count to [number]', 10);` (of course, you normally pick a shorter function name, like "_")